# print QR code on zebra printer with .net/c# application

Tags: .net, zebra-printers, zpl

I am developing a windows application. In which i get a string. I want to print that string as a QR code On zebra printer. One more requirement is , string should be printed below the QR code. Please help to find out the solution.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) are the docs for the ZPL language.
There you will find information about the commands you will mostly need for your task as a starting point:

- `^A`
- `^BQ`
- `^FD`
- `^FH`
- `^FO`
- `^FS`
- `^XA`
- `^XZ`